# Laravel Eloquent complex Subquery

Tags: laravel, eloquent, subquery

I have Following query. I want to rewrite this into Laravel Eloquernt.

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM CashTransaction AS A 
  WHERE A.Flag=0 
    AND A.IsCancel=0 
    AND A.Amount-ifnull((
        SELECT sum(ifnull(Bills.Amount,0)) 
          FROM CashTransaction AS Bills 
          WHERE A.ContractID=Bills.ContractID 
            AND Bills.Flag=2 
            AND Bills.IsCancel=0),0) > 0
```

So I could write upto

```
      $commissionDepositCount = CashTransaction::where('Flag', 0)
            ->where('IsCancel',0)

        ->where('Amount','>',function($query){
                $query->from('CashTransaction')
                    
        })

        ->when($user->Level < 5,function($query) use($user){
            $query->where('SenderID',$user->id);
            })
        ->count()
```

I cannot find how to write subqueries that

```
A.Amount-ifnull((
        SELECT sum(ifnull(Bills.Amount,0)) 
          FROM CashTransaction AS Bills 
          WHERE A.ContractID=Bills.ContractID 
            AND Bills.Flag=2 
            AND Bills.IsCancel=0),0) > 0
```

Can Anyone help me with this?

Comment: `$commissionDepositCount = CashTransaction::selectRaw('count(*) as cnt')
    ->from(DB::raw('(select * from CashTransaction where Flag = 0 and IsCancel = 0) as A'))
    ->join(DB::raw('(select ContractID, sum(ifnull(Amount, 0)) as Amount from CashTransaction where Flag = 2 and IsCancel = 0 group by ContractID) as B'), function($join) {
        $join->on('A.ContractID', '=', 'B.ContractID');
    })
    ->havingRaw('A.Amount - ifnull(B.Amount, 0) > 0')
    ->count();`

Comment: $commissionDepositCount = CashTransaction::where('Flag', 0)
            ->where('IsCancel',0)
        ->where('Amount','>',DB::raw('IFNULL((select sum(ifnull(Bills.Amount, 0)) from CashTransaction as Bills where `CashTransaction`.`ContractID` = ContractID and `Flag` = 2 and `IsCancel` = 0),0)'))
        ->when($user->Level < 5,function($query) use($user){
            $query->where('SenderID',$user->id);
            })
        ->count()